# Pinescript Multiple Time Frame

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wanted to set up a buy/sell signal in the main chart using the RSI values. I am looking for an example or script to use multiple timeframes in the same indicator chart. Say RSI based on the default time frame and secondary time frame?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `security()` function to request data from other timeframes.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

rsi_curr = ta.rsi(close, 14)
rsi_15_min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", rsi_curr)

plot(rsi_curr, color=color.green)
plot(rsi_15_min, color=color.red)
```

Read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add an extra input (rsi_res) to choose timeframe

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

rsi_curr = ta.rsi(close, 14)
rsi_res = input.timeframe(title="Enter Timeframe",defval="15")
rsi_15_min = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", rsi_curr)

plot(rsi_curr, color=color.green)
plot(rsi_15_min, color=color.red)
```

if you are using Version 4

```
//@version=4
indicator("My script")

rsi_curr = rsi(close, 14)
rsi_reso = input(title="Enter TimeFrame",type=input.resolution,defval="15")
rsi_15_min = security(syminfo.tickerid,rsi_reso, rsi_curr)

plot(rsi_curr, color=color.green)
plot(rsi_15_min, color=color.red)
```