# Adding indicator filter to existing strategy

Tags: pine-script, trading

I have an existing script for a strategy that uses the SuperTrend indicator on a 5 minute chart.  I would like to add a second SuperTrend indicator to the strategy, which pulls its data from 4 hour bars, as a filter to the current strategy.  So the strategy would only implement long trades (it is a long only strategy) when the 4hr supertrend is also green (bullish).

Having trouble with doing this at the moment.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

I tried searching for previous answers on adding another indicator but none have worked thus far

Comment: What trouble are you having? You should use the `security()` function for that. There are hundreds of similar question here.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72084919/7209631) is an answer for you.